# How o use Ransack with find_by_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

How can I use Ransack with "find_by_sql"?
I generally do this:

```
def index

  @m = Mymodel.ransack(params[:q])
  @mymodels = @m.result.page(params[:page]) 

end
```

Can I use Ransack when doing a custom query?:

```
@mymodels = Mymodel.find_by_sql(["SELECT ... ", current_user])
```

Comment: Maybe using a scope, https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#using-scopesclass-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it correctly, this is want you want:

```
def index
  @m = Mymodel.ransack(params[:q])
  @mymodels = @m.result.page(param[:page]).where(user: current_user)
end
```

To answer your question directly though, you can convert it to an SQL string, but you won't (or would be hard) be able to use `current_user` as an argument:

```
def index
  @m = Mymodel.ransack(params[:q])
  sql = @m.result.page(param[:page]).to_sql
  @mymodels = Mymodel.find_by_sql(sql, current_user)
  # the line just above won't work immediately because you'll need to
  # modify the `sql` variable manually by inserting the `?` that you'll
  # need to map that to the `current_user` that you passed as an argument
end
```